# Why all vector space have a span set?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I thought about this question, but I don't sure if my proof is correct. In the book, he put this question like a observation of span sets' definition, so I tried proof this.

My attempt:

Suppose that exists a vector space $V$ such that there isn't a span set $S = \{ v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n \}$, so exists a $v_{n+1} \in V$ such that $v_{n+1} \neq \sum_{i=1}^{i=n} v_i$, so $S \cup \{ v_{n+1} \}$ can be a span set of $V$, but can be exists $v_{n+2} \in V$ such that $v_{n+2} \neq \sum_{i=1}^{i=n+1},  v_i$, so $S \cup \{ v_{n+1}, v_{n+2} \}$ can be a span set of $V$ and we can be in this cycle infinitely. My doubt is what ensures that doesn't exists infinitely many vectors that can be span by a span set?

Comment: Is there some restriction on the span set? If not just take  the entire  vector space, it will obviously span itself.

Comment: Yes, can be the entire vector space, I just read the definition about span again and here say that "$\mathbb{B} \subset V$ is a span set of $V$ if all element of $V$ can be wriiten by a linear combination of a $\textbf{finite number of elements}$ of $\mathbb{B}$" I read wrong before and I was thinking that $\mathbb{B}$ was infinite, but thank you for your help!

Comment: I see. Yes, to get any one element you must only use finitely many elements from the span set, but the set still can be infinite.

Comment: Where you say "infinite vectors", do you mean "infinitely many vectors"? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, yes, sorry, I'm not ver good at english, but the question was solved.

Answer (score 9):

Your argument doesn't work - there are indeed vector spaces which have no finite spanning set (an interesting example of this is $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space). However, there is a much simpler proof: if $V$ is a vector space, then $V$ is a spanning set of itself.

If you want a *basis* - that is, a spanning set which is linearly independent - then things are much trickier. In fact, without the axiom of choice, they need not exist! We can however construct a basis for $V$ if the axiom of choice holds, using either Zorn's Lemma or transfinite induction (they're ultimately the same, just packaged differently).